# Creating translation path in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a single-page website with an option to translate from English to another language.

I use `const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");`

And then a button to switch language

```
<button 
       title={lang === "en" ? "Translate" : "Read in english"}
       onClick={() => {lang === "en" ? setLang("other") : setLang("en")}}>{lang === "en" ? "" : ""}                  
</button>
```

I then use ternary operators to ask what the page's language is, and show different bits of text.

My question is, how do I pass this change to the window's url (like `/other/`) and allow the user to enter the app from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/other/` page should be valid and already created dynamically (in your `gatsby-node.js`) or statically (in your `/pages/` folder), otherwise, it will throw the 404 page.

Said that, in your case, being a SPA, I think the best approach is to redirect the user to a new page using `window` object or the [built-in `navigate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function). Something like this should work:

```
   const handleClick= () => {
      lang === "en" ? setLang("other") : setLang("en");
      navigate("/other/") // alternatively use window.location 
   }


    <button 
           title={lang === "en" ? "Translate" : "Read in english"}
           onClick={handleClick}                  
    </button>
```

The idea is to delegate the responsibility of handling the redirection to an outer function (`handleClick`), keeping the `setLang` functionality but adding the navigation redirect. Keep in mind that using `window.location` will force a refresh of the whole page.

Comment: I get the second part (the redirect), but not the first. How do I create another page (could be statically) without repeating my index.js?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that your paths will be `/` (for index) and `/en` (for english), if you want a "static" approach your `/pages` folder should be `/pages/index.js` (for the `/`) and `/pages/en.js` (for the `/en`). I don't know if I clarify your doubts. Just let me know

Comment: Yes, I also understand that. I just don't know what to put it in it, since I don't want to repeat my index. Should I include it as a component? Should I do a redirect?

Comment: In that case, you should wrap your `index.js` logic into isolated components (`<SomeBillboard/>`, `<AboutMe>`, etc), create the new `/en.js` page and import the components in both pages.

Comment: Thank you! At first I thought it was extra-hard and redundant, but in the end it worked out fine. Index does english, Other does other language, and most of the Index's code now lives in a Main component.